# MacOS Folder Actions: How to return files to original folder?

Tags: finder, applescript, automator, folders, folder-action

I'm looking for a way to send a file back to its original path after adding them to a folder.

Specifically, if a file does not meet a criteria after being dropped at a folder, I want to send it back to its original folder.

I can not specify the "original" folder in the script, because the files may come from different places, and each file should go back to its own original path.

I know I can achieve something similar using a "Quick Action" instead of a Folder Action, but this is not ideal because I usually drag and drop an open file from the top bar icon.. just to the left of the file name, there is an icon which is dragable.. This icon is useful to move the file around, but does not have the 'Quick Action' menu available. Also, some end users are older people who are not as technologically advanced, and they usually prefer just to 'drag to a folder on the dock', instead of 'right click, then go to Quick Actions, then select this specific action"..

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: If it is the las file to be moved - then the Finder does have a undo

Comment: Sans what was mentioned in the comment by mmmmmm, I do not believe there is a way with basic _vanilla_ **AppleScript** to accomplish that which you are asking. To implement what was mentioned in the other comment it would have to the last _file_, **Finder** would have to have focus, then **System Events** can, e.g.,: `tell application "System Events" to keystroke "z" using command down` That said though, I'd be very careful implementing such a solution. To me, this looks like an XY Problem and one should only move a file if it's appropriate to do, not depending on some shoestring method.

Comment: Yup. You need a droplet, not a folder action. See if it should be moved first, rather than try to put it back if the move fails some requirement.

Comment: @user3439894, I feel that it is not possible easily, and I fear that it is not feasible in any robust manner.

Comment: @Tetsujin Yeah.. I know.. I've made it work as an Quick Action, but not as a Folder Action.... It would be so useful for my end users though.. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @Tono you mentioned “Specifically, if a file does not meet a criteria after being dropped at a folder, I want to send it back to its original folder.” What is the actual criteria the files need to meet?